# Using library in JS file using Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dependencies, vuetify.js, prototype

I want to use library in other external JS file So that when I summon my prototype
Something like this :

`this.$callback.handler();`

My prototype :

```
export default function(Vue, options = {}) {
    Vue.callback = {
        handler: () => {
            // this.$dialog.notify.success(
            //     "Text here",
            //     {
            //         position: "top-right",
            //         timeout: 5000
            //     }
            // );
        }
    };
    Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
        $callback: {
            get: () => {
                return Vue.callback;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So `this.$dialog` not recognized in this case (Note well : 'dialog' is vuetify-dialog library based on Vuetifyjs)

Also i tried to implement VueityDialog in my app.js using:

```
import Callback from "./apis/Callback";
Vue.use(Callback, { context: { VuetifyDialog } });
```

Any solution ?

Comment: Use a regular function for `handler` and `$callback.get`.

Comment: Can you please show me snippet i will be thankful for you